# RabbitMQ get list of bindings for an exchange

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I would like to list all bindings for an exchange programmatically, preferably using the Java Client API.

I know there are ways of doing this through REST calls via `http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/<my_exchange>/bindings/source`, but is there a programmatic way of getting the same information as well?